# Action Controllers and filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing an app where an admin can see a group of users in HTML tables that are filtered by ":platoon => A,B,C,D"

All users are stored in a "users model" and I'm trying to have multiple HTML tables on one page showing only the users associated to that platoon.

UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @a_platoon = @users.where(:platoon => @A)
    @b_platoon = @users.where(:platoon => @B)
    @c_platoon = @users.where(:platoon => @C)
    @d_platoon = @users.where(:platoon => @D)
  end
end
```

and in my index.html.erb:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Reg Number</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Alt Phone</th>
    <th colspan="7"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <% @b_platoon.each do |b_platoon| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= b_platoon.name %></td>
      <td><%= b_platoon.reg_number %></td>
      <td><%= b_platoon.phone %></td>
      <td><%= b_platoon.alt_phone %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

The goal here is to display all the users associated with b_platoon.

I'm not getting any errors, but my table just displays blank. I believe my problem lies in the controller methods but I'm not skilled enough to find it and I struggled with finding helpful documentation.

If it may help, heres my schema for my "Users" model:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "email", default: "", null: false
  t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
  t.string "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "name"
  t.integer "reg_number"
  t.string "platoon"
  t.string "phone"
  t.string "alt_phone"
  t.boolean "admin", default: false
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end
```

Comment: This is typo mistake or ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `b_platoon.your_field` instead `user.your_field`

```
<% @b_platoon.each do |b_platoon| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= b_platoon.name %></td>
      <td><%= b_platoon.reg_number %></td>
      <td><%= b_platoon.phone %></td>
      <td><%= b_platoon.alt_phone %></td>
   </tr> 
<% end %>
```

You must call methods on *enumerator* in a `.each`

Comment: This makes sense. I've updated my code, but my table is still blank. Any further suggestions?

Comment: How are platoon fields recorded in the database? Just a letter? Try to `@b_platoon = @users.where(platoon: 'B')`